# Apache Jena SPARQL query will not abort

Tags: java, swing, sparql, jena

I'm having a problem in my Java application where Apache Jena will never stop a SPARQL query until it's finished, even if I explicitly tell it to stop. Here's the code that gets called to run a query:

```
try {
    Model union = null;
    union = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_RULE_INF);
    if (ontologies != null)
        for (OntModel om : ontologies)
            union = ModelFactory.createUnion(union, om);
    Reasoner reasoner = ReasonerRegistry.getOWLReasoner();
    reasoner = reasoner.bindSchema(union);
    InfModel infmodel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, triples);

    query_running = true;
    Query query = QueryFactory.create(query_string);
    query_execution = QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, infmodel);
    ResultSet rs = query_execution.execSelect();
    for ( ; rs.hasNext(); ) {
        // do stuff with results
    }

} catch (Exception e) {}
finally {
    stopQuery();
}
```

`stopQuery()` gets called at the end, but the method is also called when the user hits a "cancel" button. Here's what that method looks like:

```
public void stopQuery() {
    try {
        if (query_execution != null) {
            //query_execution.close();
            query_execution.abort();
            query_execution = null;
            System.out.println("STOPPED");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    query_running = false;
}
```

When the cancel button is hit while a query is running (10+ minutes on a relatively small dataset...?), the method gets called, but the query continues to run in the background. I know it's still running because I can see the application in task manager taking up 30%+ CPU until the query presumably completes. I've tried `.abort()`, `.close()`, and both at the same time, but I cannot figure out how to stop the query mid-execution. I've even tried wrapping the query code in a separate thread, but that doesn't work either. It makes sense that threading wouldn't solve the problem because the thread needs to see the interrupt request, but the code is freezing on a particular line. The code seems to freeze on `rs.hasNext()`, but not the first check. It will run quickly with the first x results of the ResultSet (which are likely explicit statements it finds easily), but then it will seem to freeze for a long while after that, likely searching for implicit results with the reasoner. How can I force the query to stop? I don't want to use a timeout -- I want the user to have the option to stop the query or let it play out. This problem is not specific to any one query or dataset.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Apache Jena is this?

Comment: @AndyS I'm using Jena 4.3.0. I just updated to 4.5.0 (latest) and the issue persists.

Comment: If some results come out then it stalls, it might be the garbage collector - the system is nearly full and the GC is working harder and harder. This leads to unpredicate very log pauses. Or it might be in the nature of the ontology. You can test the first by changing the heap size and running the same setup with different heaps. You can test the second by removing parts of the ontology and seeing what happens.